# Java Timezones - Get Timezones in US or Canada

Tags: java, timezone

Is there any way to filter out the TimeZoneIDs to only include time zones associated with the United States or Canada?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

I am returning all available IDs using TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(). I can filter these on whether they include 'America' or 'Canada', but this includes a number of time zones that are not applicable for my application.

Comment: There aren't many (12 or something, if you want to include the overseas territories?), just list them out by hand.

Comment: @AndyTurner I count 29 for the US alone (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones, sort by Country Code, ignore the links)

Comment: @Sören according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States, there are 11 defined by 15 USC 260.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's current time zones. The time zone database (which is used by Java) also includes historical differences.

Comment: `TimeZone` is a legacy class, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes, defined in JSR 310, and built into Java 8+. Instead use `java.time.ZoneId` and`ZoneOffset`. For Java 6 & 7, use the ThreeTen-Backport library.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I can filter these on whether they include 'America' or 'Canada', but this includes a number of time zones that are not applicable for my application."*

You'll need to continue the filter; what time-zones are not applicable?

Here is the *Wikipedia* article on the *"timezone" database*.
*[Wikipedia – Tz_database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)*.

Additionally, if you're using a *Unix* system, you can typically find the *database* in the *`/usr/share/zoneinfo/`* folder.

And, here is a high-resolution image of the *time-zone* areas.
*[Wikimedia – World_Time_Zones_Map.png](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/World_Time_Zones_Map.png)*.

You can try filtering by the *offset* value, if this improves the precision.

```java
Stream.of(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
      .filter(x -> {
          int v = TimeZone.getTimeZone(x).getRawOffset();
          return v >= -9 * 3_600_000 && v <= -5 * 3_600_000;
      });
```

Here is a sorted output.

```
AST
America/Anchorage
America/Atikokan
America/Bahia_Banderas
America/Belize
America/Bogota
America/Boise
America/Cambridge_Bay
America/Cancun
America/Cayman
America/Chicago
America/Chihuahua
America/Ciudad_Juarez
America/Coral_Harbour
America/Costa_Rica
America/Creston
America/Dawson
America/Dawson_Creek
America/Denver
America/Detroit
America/Edmonton
America/Eirunepe
America/El_Salvador
America/Ensenada
America/Fort_Nelson
America/Fort_Wayne
America/Grand_Turk
America/Guatemala
America/Guayaquil
America/Havana
America/Hermosillo
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Knox
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Petersburg
America/Indiana/Tell_City
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Indiana/Vincennes
America/Indiana/Winamac
America/Indianapolis
America/Inuvik
America/Iqaluit
America/Jamaica
America/Juneau
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/Kentucky/Monticello
America/Knox_IN
America/Lima
America/Los_Angeles
America/Louisville
America/Managua
America/Matamoros
America/Mazatlan
America/Menominee
America/Merida
America/Metlakatla
America/Mexico_City
America/Monterrey
America/Montreal
America/Nassau
America/New_York
America/Nipigon
America/Nome
America/North_Dakota/Beulah
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
America/Ojinaga
America/Panama
America/Pangnirtung
America/Phoenix
America/Port-au-Prince
America/Porto_Acre
America/Rainy_River
America/Rankin_Inlet
America/Regina
America/Resolute
America/Rio_Branco
America/Santa_Isabel
America/Shiprock
America/Sitka
America/Swift_Current
America/Tegucigalpa
America/Thunder_Bay
America/Tijuana
America/Toronto
America/Vancouver
America/Whitehorse
America/Winnipeg
America/Yakutat
America/Yellowknife
Brazil/Acre
CST
CST6CDT
Canada/Central
Canada/Eastern
Canada/Mountain
Canada/Pacific
Canada/Saskatchewan
Canada/Yukon
Chile/EasterIsland
Cuba
EST
EST5EDT
Etc/GMT+5
Etc/GMT+6
Etc/GMT+7
Etc/GMT+8
Etc/GMT+9
IET
Jamaica
MST
MST7MDT
Mexico/BajaNorte
Mexico/BajaSur
Mexico/General
Navajo
PNT
PST
PST8PDT
Pacific/Easter
Pacific/Galapagos
Pacific/Gambier
Pacific/Pitcairn
SystemV/CST6
SystemV/CST6CDT
SystemV/EST5
SystemV/EST5EDT
SystemV/MST7
SystemV/MST7MDT
SystemV/PST8
SystemV/PST8PDT
SystemV/YST9
SystemV/YST9YDT
US/Alaska
US/Arizona
US/Central
US/East-Indiana
US/Eastern
US/Indiana-Starke
US/Michigan
US/Mountain
US/Pacific
```

Comment: That's still a lot of Latin America in there.